# How to write a condition inside a cats() string-concatenation in SAS

Tags: sas, string-concatenation

Is it possible to write a condition inside a cats() function?

Something like this:

```
data ...
   ...
   line2=cats('xxxx',if (severity=.) then 'missing' else severity,'yyyyy');
   ...
```

I would like to do this in order to write a json file.
Because severity is a numeric variable, when it's missing it's a `.` and that create invalid json files.
I'm searching for a way to replace these dots with a string in the json like  *e.g.* 'missing' in my example.

EDIT: Forgot to say I'm in a data step here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use the `IFC()` function?

```
ifc(severity=.,'missing',put(severity,best12.))
```

Of define a format.

```
proc format ;
  value severity .='missing' other=[best12.];
run;
...
line2=cats('xxxx',put(severity,severity.),'yyyyy')
```

Comment: The format is probably the best approach, didn't think of it. Thanks